# flash AS3 custom button rollover (windows 7 style)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, rollover

**NOTE:**
*I chose to keep the history of the topic cause I think the searching process might be usefull to someone. If you want the solution go to the bottom of my post.*

I searched but I didnt find my answer either on Google and StackOverflow (not even a single tutorial on it).
I would like to create a rollover highlight on a button, like the windows 7 taskbar. The highlight moves and is function of where the mouse is on the button. I dont want any image on my button (only color gradient) to keep a standard component.
How can I apply this rollover effect?

Back, I tried to run this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
             minWidth="65" minHeight="22"
             creationComplete="GlassButtonSkin_creationCompleteHandler(event)"> 

    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]</fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function GlassButtonSkin_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverHandler);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mouseClickHandler);
            }

            private function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                this.overEffectRadialGradient.y = event.stageY;
                this.labelDisplay.text = "your in";
                this.commitProperties();
            }
            private function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                this.labelDisplay.text = "your in";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up"/> 
        <s:State name="over"/> 
        <s:State name="down"/> 
        <s:State name="disabled"/> 
    </s:states>

    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="up" toState="over" autoReverse="true">
            <s:Fade target="{overEffect}" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="500"/>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>




    <!-- inner border --> 
    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" id="innerBorder" radiusX="4" radiusY="4">
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="innerBorderStroke" weight="1" color="#ffffff" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- outer border --> 
    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" id="outerBorder" radiusX="4" radiusY="4">
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="outerBorderStroke" weight="1" color="#000000"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- fill -->
    <!--- Defines the appearance of the Button component's background. -->
    <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="0.5" color="#000000"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Rect id="backgroundTopPart" left="1" right="1" top="1" height="50%"
            includeIn="up,over,disabled">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#ffffff" alpha="0.6"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#ffffff" alpha="0.2"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Rect id="overEffect" left="1" right="1" bottom="1" height="50%" radiusX="4" radiusY="4"
            includeIn="over,down">
        <s:fill>        
            <s:RadialGradient id="overEffectRadialGradient" x="{width*0.5}" y="{height*0.5}" scaleY="{height}" scaleX="{width/1.5}">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#8dbdff" alpha="0.7" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="#8dbdff" alpha="0"/>
            </s:RadialGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>


    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             text="Send"
             textAlign="center" 
             verticalAlign="middle" 
             color="#FFFFFF"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1" 
             left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>



</s:SparkSkin>
```

The problem is that no event is captured. I tried to change the label text on a click event to test but it just doesn't work at all (no event handle). It's really strange. Can you bring some help please?

**EDIT 15/11/11**
I found that my creationCompleteHandler needed a parent.mouseChildren = true; to capture the mouse events. I put it and now I can see that mouse events are captured but my rollovereffect is not displayed anymore even if i delete the transition of states and I play with the visible = true/false; of the effect in my mouse over handler.

**LAST EDIT**
I finally found the solution of my problem, thanks to all.
My solution:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
             minWidth="65" minHeight="22"
             creationComplete="GlassButtonSkin_creationCompleteHandler(event)"> 

    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]</fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.graphics.RadialGradient;

            import spark.effects.Fade;
            import spark.effects.animation.RepeatBehavior;

            [Bindable]
            private var rectRollOverEffect:Rect = new Rect();
            private var radialGradientRollOverEffect:RadialGradient = new RadialGradient();
            private var gradientEntryRollOverEffect1:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0x8dbdff,NaN,0.7);
            private var gradientEntryRollOverEffect2:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0x8dbdff,NaN,0);
            private var indexOfRollOverEffect:int;
            private var myFade:Fade;

            protected function GlassButtonSkin_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
                parent.mouseChildren = true;
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoveHandler,true);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOutHandler,true);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverHandler,true);

                this.addElement(rectRollOverEffect);
                indexOfRollOverEffect = this.getElementIndex(rectRollOverEffect);
                this.removeElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect);
            }

            private function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                if(this.currentState == "disabled")
                    return;

                createRollOverEffect(event,0);

                myFade = new Fade(this.getElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect));
                myFade.alphaFrom = 0;
                myFade.alphaTo = 1;
                myFade.duration = 200;
                myFade.end();
                myFade.play();
            }

            private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                if(this.currentState == "disabled")
                    return;

                this.removeElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect);
                createRollOverEffect(event,1);
            }

            private function mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                if(this.currentState == "disabled")
                    return;

                this.removeElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect);
            }

            private function createRollOverEffect(event:MouseEvent,alpha:int):void{
                rectRollOverEffect.alpha = alpha;
                rectRollOverEffect.left = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.right = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.bottom = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.top = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.radiusX = 4;
                rectRollOverEffect.radiusY = 4;

                radialGradientRollOverEffect.entries = [gradientEntryRollOverEffect1,gradientEntryRollOverEffect2];
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.x = event.localX;
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.y = height-2;
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.scaleX = width/1.5;
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.scaleY = height;

                rectRollOverEffect.fill = radialGradientRollOverEffect;

                this.addElementAt(rectRollOverEffect,indexOfRollOverEffect);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up"/> 
        <s:State name="over"/> 
        <s:State name="down"/> 
        <s:State name="disabled"/> 
    </s:states>

    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="over" toState="disabled">
            <s:CallAction target="{this}" functionName="removeElement" args="{[this.rectRollOverEffect]}"/>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>



    <!-- outer border --> 
    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" id="outerBorder" radiusX="4" radiusY="4">
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="outerBorderStroke" weight="1" color="#ffffff" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- inner border --> 
    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" id="innerBorder" radiusX="4" radiusY="4">
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="innerBorderStroke" weight="1" color="#000000"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- fill -->
    <!--- Defines the appearance of the Button component's background. -->
    <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="0.5" color="#000000"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Rect id="backgroundTopPart" left="1" right="1" top="1" height="50%"
            includeIn="up,over,disabled">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#ffffff" alpha="0.5" ratio="0.1"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#ffffff" alpha="0.1"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>


    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             text="Send"
             textAlign="center" 
             verticalAlign="middle" 
             color="#FFFFFF"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1" 
             left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>

    <s:Rect id="disableForeground" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
            includeIn="disabled">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#7B7B7B" alpha="0.6" ratio="0.1"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#aaaaaa" alpha="0.3"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>


</s:SparkSkin>
```

Comment: Can you link to a picture or a video of the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is a link for tha W7 task bar effect : [capture]http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/mgrayson/images/1689351/500x36.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a few steps to get started:

1. Create the gradient. Could be:

   - a predefined image
   - a circle, filled with an outer gradient color set to transparent. Maybe needs to be transformed into an ellipse.
2. Mask the gradient with the area of the button.
3. Listen for [mouse over](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_OVER) and [mouse out](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_OUT) events on the button's area. Update the position of the gradient to the mouse position (or only `mouse.y`) on [mouse move](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_MOVE).

I can't promise that it will look exactly like in the windows 7 taskbar, as it depends on the button's background and the shape of the gradient. I'm no sure if there are additional effects used there. You can spice up things a little bit by adding more gradients that change their transparency according to the mouse distance and experimenting with [multiply blend mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html#MULTIPLY) which gives nice effects.

---

***Update*** -   I think `this.overEffectRadialGradient.y = event.stageY;` is using the wrong coordinates. It may works if the button is at `0,0` though. The local coordinates should be the correct ones: `event.localY`.

Comment: Ok thanks very much I will try with your ideas and if it renders good enough I will post th code there.

Comment: I'm blocked at the moment (see the edit of my post above). If you could help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: @TheFrenchGuy  Updated. Sorry but I'm not sure I can be of much help, as I don't have much experience with flex, just with pure AS. Your code looks good as far as I can tell. If you run into problems and no one posts an answer, you should create new questions for the specific problem to attract more attention.